# The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server

Tags: php, mysql, apache, phpmyadmin

I have installed Xampp on windows 8. Apache and Mysql are running fine on port [4433,8080] (changed apache default port) and 3307 respectively.
I am getting the Xampp dashboard page but when Ii click on `phpMyAdmin` link is giving me the following error:

> The requested URL /phpmyadmin/ was not found on this server.

Additionally, a 404 Not Found error was encountered while trying to use an ErrorDocument to handle the request. I am stuck in this step, I searched a lot but not worked for me. I need help on clarifying how can I fix the error message.

Comment: Does the phpMyAdmin link look like `http://localhost:8080/phpmyadmin/`?

Comment: my phpmyadmin folder is also in small case if it affects!

Comment: @JiriHrazdil does folder name letter case affects?

Answer (score 0):

The default installation of XAMPP sets the `phpMyAdmin` folder as `phpMyAdmin` - pay attention of the case of letters.

Comment: i searched and found one answer to change the default folder name to small case so i did that :|